# C# Портативность на разные версии windows

Tags: c#

Как можно сделать чтоб от xp до win10 можно было работать с программой в которой есть sql база данных.

Comment: `программой в которой есть sql база данных` что это значит?

Comment: Делайте под .NET Framework 4.0 (который работает с XP), как БД можно использовать SQLite (я так понимаю БД на клиенте). В чём именно проблема?

Comment: Погуглите понятие: CLR Any CPU для понимания вопроса

Comment: @Саша Здесь сайт, где решают конкретные вопросы. Для того, чтобы написать программу, у вас два варианта 1) нанять программиста, 2) стать программистом. Здесь ни с тем, ни с другим не помогут. Максимум дадут общие советы.